# Robocopy % sign in destination folder path

Tags: robocopy

I have \E%3A\ in my destination folder path where I want to copy a file but when running this the files are copied into a new folder \EA\ - so in the incorrect location.  is there any solution to this? I am making copy over different servers.

Thanks in advance

MR

Comment: Oh God, they had the same silly bug in MSBuild from .NET 4. (fixed in .NET 4.5 ;p)

Comment: im doign this from CMD which removes %3 and creates fodler called 3A

Comment: It is doing something really stupid then :( MSBuild would actually try to convert `%3A` to `:` and fail.

Comment: any work round to ensure it uses E%3A and not convert to EA?!?!